# TV has the wrong resolution

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, resolution

I have to reinstall windows 10. Im using my LG TV as secondary monitor and even when said is 1920x1080 the display is in a different resolution.

Those bluestack windows are the same size but on the LG (left) show much bigger.

[image]

On the Nvidea control panel show the resolution is 1080p

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your first display is not 1920x1080; you can check it out in the Nvidia control panel, but choosing that "Ancor Communic..." monitor. See if it's using a resolution other than 1080p, which would cause the images to be at different sizes. I hope it's helpful.

Comment: both are same resolution but monitor doesn't say 1080p. Just 1920x1200